# How to place three bar plots side by side in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have three data frames as below. How do I put three bar plots side by side in single frame?

**D1:-**

main_sector
Others                                     2739
Cleantech / Semiconductors                 2150
Social, Finance, Analytics, Advertising    1817

**D2:-**

main_sector
Others                                     138
Cleantech / Semiconductors                 114
Social, Finance, Analytics, Advertising     95

**D3:-**

main_sector
Others                                     102
News, Search and Messaging                  49
Social, Finance, Analytics, Advertising     32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use concat to form a single data frame. for more info refer [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
df_concat = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df_concat, df3], axis=1)
```